# Noisy output instead of image?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have everything in my scene working fine , but when I render my image is shows up like this?

Camera settings on the right

[image]

Comment: could you upload your .blend file?

Comment: PW : knuckles  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hidden cube (`Arm.Hand.Target`) and a hidden sphere (`Arm.Elbow.Target`) in your scene, which are blocking the camera.

Rendered shading in BI doesn't work quite the same as in cycles, the render visibility setting (camera icon in the outliner) is used in the viewport when in rendered view.